# TypeError: Cannot access member 'match' of undefined

Tags: web3js

I can't call the functions of the metaCoin contract on my private chain within the geth console from another added peer node.

I've deployed the metaCoin contract byTruffle on my computer,
https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts

and I'm trying to call the functions from another node linked together on my private chain. 
I've only managed to find the exact same problem described here, but my version of Web3.js is already 1.0.0-beta.55

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/898

Here is the code I tried so far

```
$ mkdir web3test && cd web3test

$ npm init

$ npm install web3 --save

var Web3 = require("web3");

var web3 = new Web3();

web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var abi = [myabi}];

var address = "myaddress";

var metacoin = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);

var account_one = web3.eth.accounts[0];

var account_one_balance = metacoin.getBalance.call(account_one);
```

https://my.oschina.net/u/2349981/blog/863731

This is the message I'm getting whenever I type in metacoin.getBalance.call(account_one)
`TypeError: Cannot access member 'match' of undefined`

```
at web3.js:539:14

at web3.js:660:16

at filter ()(<native code>)

at web3.js:659:24

at web3.js:850:16

at map ()(<native code>)

at web3.js:849:12

at web3.js:691:25

at web3.js:4059:46

at web3.js:4098:19
```